# Is there any simple way to create a list of formula in R

Tags: r, list, regression, formula

Here I want to create a list of formula for a simple linear regression, 2nd and 3rd order polynomial models. I just did this. It could be ok for a few variables but my data is a quite lot variables. So how could I avoid overloading work using another way to do the same thing?

```
ind1.lm <- lm(dep ~ ind1, data = df)
ind1.qd <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind1, 2, raw = TRUE), data = df)
ind1.cb <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind1, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df)

ind2.lm <- lm(dep ~ ind2, data = datAll)
ind2.qd <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind2, 2, raw = TRUE), data = df)
ind2.cb <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind2, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df)

ind3.lm <- lm(dep ~ ind3, data = df)
ind3.qd <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind3, 2, raw = TRUE), data = df)
ind3.cb <- lm(dep ~ poly(ind3, 3, raw = TRUE), data = df)

formula.list <- list(as.formula(ind1.lm), as.formula(ind1.qd), 
    as.formula(ind1.cb), as.formula(ind2.lm), as.formula(ind2.qd), 
    as.formula(ind2.cb), as.formula(ind3.lm), as.formula(ind3.qd), 
    as.formula(ind3.cb))

 formula.list
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you are creating the model instead of the formula `lm(dep ~ ind1, data = df)`  If you want to create the formula, use `paste`

Comment: @ akrun. thank you. This is the problem that I don't get to use paste() for polynomial model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the independent variables and the formats of the formulas and from that we can get the formula strings.  Since `lm` accepts strings as formulas we can then apply over that giving a list of `lm` objects whose names are the formulas.

```
ind <- c("ind1", "ind2", "ind3")
fmt <- c("dep ~ %s", 
         "dep ~ poly(%s, 2, raw=TRUE)", 
         "dep ~ poly(%s, 3, raw=TRUE)")

fo.strings <- c(outer(fmt, ind, sprintf))

sapply(fo.strings, lm, data = df, simplify = FALSE)
```

Questions to SO should include reproducible code and `df` was omitted from the question but we can run it using the builtin anscombe data frame like this:

```
fmt <- c("y1~ %s", 
         "y1~ poly(%s, 2, raw=TRUE)", 
         "y1 ~ poly(%s, 2, raw=TRUE)")
ind <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
fo.strings <- c(outer(fmt, ind, sprintf))
sapply(fo.strings, lm, data = anscombe, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck. Thank you so much. this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck. I wanna make sure if it is possible to plot the 3 models for each independent variable vs dep variable along with their equation and R2  just to compare the models result for each predictor variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph